# Get rabbitmq plugin dir location through command line

Tags: shell, plugins, command-line, location, rabbitmq

I need to get the Rabbitmq plugin installation dir programmatically through command line. I'm trying to parse rabbitmqctl environment command, but the result isn't a JSON formatted string. It seems that it is a proprietary pattern...

So, I've tried to do this:

```
$ rabbitmqctl environment |grep plugins_dir | awk -F , '{ print $2 }' | tr -d '\"}'
```

Sometimes the above command works when the result returns the plugins_dir string on the same line of the location itself, in my case: "/usr/lib/rabbitmq/lib/rabbitmq_server-3.5.4/sbin/../plugins"

But sometimes, that command returns the plugin dir location in the other line, breaking my parser.

```
$ rabbitmqctl environment |grep -A 2 plugins_dir 
      {plugins_dir,
          "/usr/lib/rabbitmq/lib/rabbitmq_server-3.5.4/sbin/../plugins"},
      {plugins_expand_dir,
```

Is there an easy way to get the plugin dir location?

Answer (score 3):

Try something like:

`./sbin/rabbitmqctl eval 'application:get_env(rabbit, plugins_dir).'`

For more info see http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/application.html